# Shared address space in Cython

Tags: openmp, cython

I have the following `Cython` code:

```
from cython import parallel
from libc.stdio cimport printf
cdef extern from "unistd.h" nogil:
   int usleep(int);

def test_func():
    cdef int var = -1
    with nogil, parallel.parallel(num_threads=4):
        var = parallel.threadid()
        usleep(100000)
        printf("Var: %d\n", var)
```

After compiling and launching in `python3` console I get:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.test_func()
Var: 3
Var: 0
Var: 2
Var: 1
```

That means, each thread has its own address space.

However, I would like to have `C++` `OpenMP` behavior, duplicating this:

```
#include "omp.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int v=-1;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    v=omp_get_thread_num();
    usleep(100000);
    printf("Var: %d\n", v);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

which outputs something like this:

```
Var: 3
Var: 3
Var: 3
Var: 3
```

Thus, question: is it possible to get shared address space in `Cython` parallelized blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a hacky way of doing it, but using a pointer to `var` you look to be able to trick it

```
def test_func2():
    cdef int var = -1
    cdef int* var_ptr = &var
    with nogil, parallel.parallel(num_threads=4):
        var_ptr[0] = parallel.threadid()
        usleep(100000)
        printf("Var: %d\n", var)
```

If you look at the generated C code then `test_func` (your version) gives the line

```
#pragma omp parallel private(__pyx_v_var) num_threads(4)
```

while `test_func2` gives

```
#pragma omp parallel  num_threads(4)
```

I think this works because you don't directly assign to it, so it isn't picked up by Cython's normal rules for what to make private. There is a risk here - if a future version of Cython got cleverer and make `var_ptr` private then it wouldn't be initialised at the start of the parallel section (so be careful and check what it's doing!).